# Tkinter/SQLite3: GUI that filters table data based on specific entry fields

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am trying to create a Tkinter GUI that based on user input, will go through a table and select out rows that match the criteria of only the entry fields that have had something inputted into them.

For example, lets say we have a table called `pets` with the columns `name`, `age` and `species`

```
 +------------------+-----------+-----------+
 | name             | age       | species   |
 +------------------+-----------+-----------+
 | Muffin           | 3         | Cat       |
 | Dash             | 8         | Dog       |
 | Winnie           | 10        | Cat       |
 | Chewie           | 1         | Hamster   |
 | Slinky           | 3         | Snake     |
 +------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

And I have this Tkinter app which a user enters the criteria they want to filter:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3

def main():

    def do_something():
        connection = sqlite3.connect("my_database.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        name = name_str.get()
        age = age_str.get()
        species = species_str.get()

        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM pets WHERE name=? AND age=? AND species=? ", (name, age, species))
        pet = cursor.fetchall()

        for row in pet:
            print(row)
    
    root = tk.Tk()

    name_str = StringVar()
    age_str = StringVar()
    species_str = StringVar()

    frame = Frame(root, padx=20, pady=20)
    frame.pack()

    name_label = Label(frame, text="Name").pack()
    name_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=name_str).pack()

    age_label = Label(frame, text="Age").pack()
    age_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=age_str).pack()

    species_label = Label(frame, text="Species").pack()
    species_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=species_str).pack()

    filter_button = Button(frame, text="Filter", command=do_something).pack()

    mainloop()

main()
```

If I want to find all the `Cats` in the table that are age `10`, I would type `10` in the `Age` field and `Cat` in the `Species` field, using the `SELECT` statement, I would hope to print out pets that match that criteria (The only one in the table being Winnie)

However, because I have not provided an entry into the `Name` field, nothing is retrieved from the table (I assume this is because the `StringVar()` becomes `NoneType` when nothing is entered so the function is looking for `name=None`)

What is the best way to implement this filtering system that allows me to search the table based **only** the the entry fields I use? Is there a better way to format my `SELECT` statement that will do this for me or will I have to create a logical function using Python code?

I have tried using `if` statements to check if the fields have an entry in them before proceeding, with two methods of trying to filter data.

The first being a list that contains the columns I want to search, and if an entry is detected in any of the fields, it would add the SQL column name to an list called `args = []`.

First attempt:

```
args = []

if len(name) == 0:
    pass
else:
    args.append("name=?")

if len(age) == 0:
    pass
else:
    args.append("age=?")

if len(species) == 0:
    pass
else:
    args.append("species=?")

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM pets WHERE {}").format(args)
```

The second method I tired was if the `if` statement detects an entry in the field, it will select all the rows that match the user input and add it onto a list, then move onto the next `if` statement with the hope that I could split the data into separate strings by index, but it didn't work how I expected it to.

Second attempt:

```
if len(name) == 0:
    pass
else:
    cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM pets WHERE name=?", [name])
    name_data = cursor.fetchall()
            
    name_list = []
            
    for row in name_data:
        name_list.append(row)


if len(age) == 0:
    pass
else:
    cursor.execute("SELECT age FROM pets WHERE age=?", [age])
    age_data = cursor.fetchall()
            
    age_list = []
            
    for row in age_data:
        age.append(row)


if len(species) == 0:
    pass
else:
    cursor.execute("SELECT species FROM pets WHERE species=?", [species])
    species_data = cursor.fetchall()
            
    species_list = []
            
    for row in species_data:
        species.append(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build the SQL dynamically:

```
def do_something():
    connection = sqlite3.connect("my_database.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    name = name_str.get().strip()
    age = age_str.get().strip()
    species = species_str.get().strip()

    conditions = []
    args = []
    if name:
        conditions.append('name = ?')
        args.append(name)
    if age:
        conditions.append('age = ?')
        args.append(age)
    if species:
        conditions.append('species = ?')
        args.append(species)

    # default select all if no condition is given
    sql = "SELECT * FROM pets"
    if conditions:
        # add the WHERE clause if any condition is given
        sql += " WHERE "+" AND ".join(conditions)

    cursor.execute(sql, args)
    pets = cursor.fetchall()

    if pets:
        for pet in pets:
            print(pet)
    else:
        print('No pet found')
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! Just a quick note, the `if` statements in my code will only work if they're written the same as in my original question.